# Dropzonejs is uploading small images but not uploading gifs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dropzone.js

This is a strange one, iv got dropzone working fine when uploading small jpeg images, but if i want to upload gifs, it wont work.

Im not getting any errors, but it showing the $_POST as empty, so i dont think its getting sent to the upload.php file.

Here is my js code

```
var previewTemplate = $('#preview-template').html();
          $('#preview-template').remove();

          Dropzone.options.uploadForm = {
              url: 'upload.php',
              maxFiles: 10,
              previewTemplate: previewTemplate,
              previewsContainer: '#uploadForm',
              createImageThumbnails: false,
              maxFilesize: 100,
              init: function() {

                    this.on("uploadprogress", function(progress) {
                      //console.log(progress);
                      //$(".progress-bar").css({"width": progress + "%"});
                    });

                    this.on('addedfile', function(file) {

                      // Called when a file is added to the list.
                      console.log('added' + file);

                    });

                    this.on('sending', function(file, xhr, formData) {

                      // Called just before each file is sent.
                      console.log('sending' + file);

                    });

                    this.on('success', function(file, json) {

                      // Called when file uploaded successfully.
                      console.log('success' + file);

                    });

              }

        };
```

Here is my upload.php file

```
    ini_set('post_max_size', '100M');
    ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '100M');
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $storeFolder = 'g/';   //2

    if (!empty($_FILES)) {

        $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];          //3

        $targetFile =  $storeFolder. $_FILES['file']['name'];  //5

        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile); //6

        echo "OK";
    } else {
        var_dump

($_FILES);
}
```

Form is here

```
<form class="dropzone" id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                          <div class="dz-message">
                              <h3>Drag and Drop Gifs Here</h3>
                              <span class="grey">or click to browse</span>
                          </div>
                          <div id="previewsContainer"></div>
                          <div id="preview-template" style="display:none;">
                              <div class="dz-details">
                                <div class="dz-filename"><span data-dz-name></span></div>
                                <div class="dz-size" data-dz-size></div>
                                <strong class="error text-danger" data-dz-errormessage></strong>
                                <div class="dz-progress"><span class="dz-upload" data-dz-uploadprogress></span></div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </form>
```

Comment: Could we see your form's code please

Comment: @legrandviking iv added it :)